# How can i fix Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas without modify the code Truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, web3js

hi i'm trying to create a graphich interface for my truffle project but i can't execute some function because of this annoying error how can i do,i have almost tried testrpc -l 4500000000 and to add to the transaction that fail the gas field.
Please Help!!!

Comment: You should consider posting your source code and give more information about the infrastructure of your project (version, library used, release, ect...)

Comment: What is your question exactly state it clear